# Ruby on Rails 4: Working with dates between database and forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I am looking for some help with converting dates back and forth from a form and database.  I have been using the following method, but it seems like there should be a better/easier way to manage this.

The code in the view:

```
  <%= f.label :issue_date, "Date Issued" %>
  <%= f.text_field :issue_date, class: 'form-control', :value => @license.issue_date.strftime("%m-%d-%Y") %>
```

The code in the controller:

```
params[:license][:issue_date] = DateTime.strptime( params[:license][:issue_date], "%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
params[:license][:expiration_date] = DateTime.strptime( params[:license][:expiration_date], "%m-%d-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

My concern is that this depends too much on the input format being correct.  For instance, if the inputs 4/2/2015 instead of 4-2-2015, it breaks the code.  I would appreciate any help or advice!  I have been reading a lot of posts on dates, but nothing specific to answering this question.

Comment: There are several things you could do: 1) client-side validation with JS, 2) server-side validation using Rails validators, 3) format the value in a `before_action` in your controller, and these are just to name a few. It's really up to you, but the important question is do you want to allow various formats for inputting the dates or do you want to restrict it?

Comment: I want to allow the user to input the date as they feel comfortable.  At some point, I will add a date picker to the field as well.  I was hoping there was a simpler solution since this seems like it would be a common problem.  So I basically need to format it manually each time, changing whatever format the user may have entered into the correct format using a "-"?

Comment: Well, you can use `.to_date` as long as the inputted date responds to the method. You can write a case statement that reformats the date for edge cases (i.e. mm/dd/yy will fail) and convert everything else to a date object before saving it in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, a date input with good UI is hard to set up in Rails, at least in my experience. If you are willing to compromise a bit on the UI, the simplest solution is to use the built-in `date_select` helper:

```
<%= f.date_select :issue_date %>
```

This will generate three select inputs, like this:

[image]

Rails will automatically handle translating the submission from these three inputs into a proper date in the database. Again, the UI is not great, but it does solve the date format validation problem.

Later, if you decide to use a Javascript date picker instead, set up the JS to ensure that the date value is always submitted to the server in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, which is what Rails expects.